# Is it possible to use the Counter function to see the ocurrences of elements in a list within a bigger list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, concatenation, counter

I am asked to make code that counts the ocurrence of each vowel in a single inputed word. Case insensitive.

So I basically want to count the ocurrence of **different elements** within a list. They way I thought of this is to create a list. `vowels=( "a" ,"e" ,"i" ,"o" ,"u" )`

Then I input the word, lowering it, etc.

```
from collections import Counter
x = input()
y = x.lower()
z = list(y)
```

Then I want to use counter so it can count all of the vowels at once.

```
C = z.Counter(vowels) 
print(C)
```

But when I run the software it shows me

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'Counter'

So what I am doing wrong? Or can you just not use counter the same way that you use count?

(I already solved the excercise using count but I'm trying to find a elegant more concise solution.)

This is the whole code I'm trying to make work:

```
from collections import Counter
x = input()
y = x.lower()
z = list(y)
vowels=[ "a" ,"e" ,"i" ,"o" ,"u" ]

C = z.Counter(vowels)

print(C)
```

Comment: ... yes, why are you doing `z.Counter`??? `z` is a `list` (note, there is no reason for `z` to be a `list`, it would work exactly the same way if you kept it as `y`, a `str` object, but in any case...) and `list` objects do not have a `.Counter` attribute.

Comment: Note, `Counter` will count the objects *you pass into it*.

Answer (score 0):

`Counter` is not an attribute nor a method of list.
Try this instead:

```
vowels = ("a", "e", "i", "o", "u")
x = input("Enter a word:") # input: aeiai
y = x.lower()
vowels_counter = {k: v for k, v in Counter(y).items() if k in vowels}
print(vowels_counter) # output: {'a': 2, 'e': 1, 'i': 2}
```